# How to format code like C# style for Java in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij for Java development, but I prefer C# like coding style. How to format like C# code style? For example:

```
     if()
     {
          /// do something
     }
     else
     {
        //// do something
     }
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java**

[image]

- Go to `Wrapping and Braces` tab.
- under `Braces placement`, there's a drop-down called `Others`, change it  to `Next Line`. (by default it is End of line). This will change bracer placement for all the places other than class and method declaration.
- If you want class and method declarations also to appear in that style,  change 2 previous drop-downs in `Braces placement` section(`In class declaration`, `In method declaration`) to `Next Line` also.

Answer (score 0):

How to configure code style for a language:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-code-style.html