# Is there an equivalent in IntelliJ for Java to .NET C# Stylecop to check for and fix code styles in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, c#, intellij-idea, code-formatting, stylecop

There are some styling built into Intellij:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39557713/394178

But in Visual Studio there is a plugin for StyleCop that highlights violations of user defined code styles that allows for quick fixing them. Is there an equivalent in IntelliJ for Java?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-code-style.html does this help?

Comment: checkstyle integration? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea